# How to use BLAS to do traditional matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix-multiplication, blas

I am trying to use BLAS (in particular, [this](https://github.com/Schultzer/libblas) implementation of BLAS) to do a simple matrix-matrix multiplication. While `blas::level3::gemm` does the operation `C <= alpha * A * B + beta * C`, I just need to do the operation `C <= A * B`. Here is my code so far:

```rust
use libblas::level3::gemm;

fn main() {
    // A dims M x N
    // B dims N x K
    let (m, n, k) = (3, 2, 3);
    let a = vec![1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.]; // 3 x 2 matrix
    let b = vec![1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.]; // 2 x 3 matrix
    let mut c = vec![0.; m * k];
    gemm('n', 'n', m, n, k, 1.0, &a, m, &b, k, 1.0, &mut c, n);
    println!("{:?}", c);
}
```

The expected result should be:

```
[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0]
```

But BLAS returns a cryptic error of `gemm 13`. I'm sure the issue is something very obvious, I just can't seem to tell what it is.